# How to obtain real time kubernetes pod metrics with a poll interval of 2secs?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, docker-container, kubelet, metrics-server

My use case is to make a kubernetes pod's metrics be available for consumption every 2 secs. It is required to poll the pod at this interval to maintain a healthy control plane (determine pods that are possibly choked and avoid routing traffic to those endpoints).

I'm using metrics-server right now, but it is not best suited for my use case.
I came across the note below, [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server).

> Metrics Server is not meant for non-autoscaling purposes. For example,
> don't use it to forward metrics to monitoring solutions, or as a
> source of monitoring solution metrics. In such cases please collect
> metrics from Kubelet /metrics/resource endpoint directly.
>
> How often metrics are scraped? Default 60 seconds, can be changed
> using metric-resolution flag. We are not recommending setting values
> below 15s, as this is the resolution of metrics calculated by Kubelet.

1. How should one use the kubelet metrics endpoint directly? All examples I've come across use `metrics.k8s.io`.
2. The other approach is to get `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpuacct.usage` reading from the docker containers directly, but there needs to be an aggregation layer. How should one design this stats aggregation layer?

Are there other approaches? What is the best recommended way to address my requirement? Thanks.

Comment: Please, try solution provided in answer section (using [`prometheus adapter`](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus-adapter) to plug into HPA) and let us know if it works for you.

Comment: ` (determine pods that are possibly choked and avoid routing traffic to those endpoints)` - Actually readiness probe does this out of the box. Removes pods from endpoint if they are not-ready for new traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to add a /metrics endpoint on your workloads and then scrape that using [prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus) and the implement the [prometheus adapter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus-adapter) to plug into HPA.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend a bit @testfile answer.

Adding metics endpoint on your workloads, scraping using prometheus and finally implementing the  [prometheus adapter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus-adapter)  to plug into HPA is a good idea.

> [Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus) is an open-source systems monitoring and alerting toolkit originally built at [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/).
>
> Prometheus scrapes metrics from instrumented jobs, either directly or via an intermediary push gateway for short-lived jobs.

[Here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/getting_started/) and [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus) you can find how to start with Prometheus.

Based on [this documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter) Prometheus Adapter can replace the [metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) on clusters that already run Prometheus and collect the appropriate metrics.

See also [this article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-prometheus-adapter-to-autoscale-custom-metrics-deployments-p1p3tl0).